# result of semantic search on java lucene

Tags: java, lucene

i've implemented the Latent Semantic Analisys on Lucene

The result of the algorithm are the matrix of 2 columns where the first is the index of the document and the second similarity.

That i want to write the response in the org.apache.lucene.search.Collector to the method search of Searcher, but i do not know how set the result in the collector object.

the code for the search method is:

```
    public void search(Weight weight, Filter filter, Collector collector) throws IOException                
{
    String textQuery = weight.getQuery().toString("contents");
    System.out.println(textQuery);
    double[][] ind;
    ind = lsa.searchOnDoc(textQuery);
    //ind contains the index and the similarity
    if (ind != null)
    {
        //construct the collector object
        for (int i=0; i<ind.length; i++)
        {
            int doc =(int) ind[i][0];
            double simi = ind[i][1]
            //collector.collect(doc);
            //collector.setScorer(sim]);
            //This is the problem
        }
    }
    else
    {
        collector = null;
    }
}
```

i don't know the right steps to copy the value of ind in the collector object.

Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite get why did you decide to shove LSI into `Searcher`.
And getting your text query from `Weight` looks especially shady - why not use the original query instead and skip all the (broken) conversions?

But the `Collector` is handled as follows.
For each segment in your index:

1. Supply it corresponding `SegmentReader` with `collector.setNextReader(reader, base)`. You can get these with `ir.getSequentialSubReaders()` and `ir.getSubReaderStarts()` on toplevel reader. So,

   - `reader` *may* be used by `collector` to load sort fields/caches during collection, and additional fields to augment search result when collection is done,
   - `base` is the number added to segment/local docIDs (they start from 0 for each segment) to convert them to index/global docIDs.
2. Supply it a `Scorer` implementation with `collector.setScorer(scorer)`.
   `collector` *may* use it during the next phase to get the score for the documents.  Though if collector only counts the results, or sorts on some stored field, or just feels so - `scorer` will be ignored.
   The only method collectors invoke on `Scorer` instance is `scorer.score()`, which should return the score (I kid you not) for the current document being collected.
3. Repeatedly call `collector.collect(id)` with monotonically increasing sequence of segment/local docIDs that match your query.

Going back to your code - make some wrapper that implements `Scorer`, use a single instance with a field that you update with `simi` on each iteration, have wrapper's `score()` method return that field, shove this instance into collector with `setScorer()` before the loop.

You also need `lsa.searchOnDoc` to return per-segment results.